# Extract from a match to next match if patten found in between

Tags: python

I am beginner in python. I am struggling with a problem which is explained below. I am sharing incomplete python script also which does not work for this problem. I would be grateful if get support or instruction for my script.

File looks like this:

```xml
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt1 Element1
    abc1 hit 1
  .
  .
</Iteration>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt2 Element2
    abc2 hit 1
  .
  .
</Iteration>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt3 Element3
    abc3 hit 1
  .
  .
</Iteration>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt4 Element4
    abc4 hit 1
  .
  .
</Iteration>
```

I need from `<Iteration>` to `</Iteration>` for Elements list match, which means for Element2 and Element4 the output file should look like this:

```xml
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt2 Element2
    abc2 hit 1
  .
  .
</Iteration>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt4 Element4
    abc4 hit 1
  .
  .
</Iteration>
```

Script

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
x = raw_input("Enter your xml file name: ")
xml = open(x)
l = raw_input("Enter your list file name: ")
lst = open(l)
Id = list()
ylist = list()
import re
for line in lst:
        stuff=line.rstrip()
        stuff.split()
        Id.append(stuff)
for ele in Id:
        for line1 in xml:
                if line1.startswith("  <Iteration_hit>"):
                        y = line1.split()
#                       print y[1]
                        if y[1] == ele: break
```

Comment: You do know that there are libraries to read/write xml files, right?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse XML. Python ships with an `xml` package just for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you... I was unaware... i will try with the libraries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't recommended to use regex to parse XML - you should use a library such as `lxml`, which you can install using `pip install lxml`. Then, you could select the appropriate elements to output using `lxml` and `XPath` as follows (I have taken the liberty of closing the `<Iteration_hit>` tags in your XML):

```
content = '''
<root>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt1 Element1
    abc1 hit 1
  </Iteration_hit>
</Iteration>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt2 Element2
    abc2 hit 1
  </Iteration_hit>
</Iteration>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt3 Element3
    abc3 hit 1
  </Iteration_hit>
</Iteration>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_hit>Elememt4 Element4
    abc4 hit 1
  </Iteration_hit>
</Iteration>
</root>
'''

from lxml import etree

tree = etree.XML(content)
target_elements = tree.xpath('//Iteration_hit[contains(., "Element2") or contains(., "Element4")]')

for element in target_elements:
    print(etree.tostring(element))
```

**Output**

```
<Iteration_hit>Elememt2 Element2
    abc2 hit 1
  </Iteration_hit>

<Iteration_hit>Elememt4 Element4
    abc4 hit 1
  </Iteration_hit>
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the desired complete script for xml parsing through Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from lxml import etree

with open('input.xml', 'r') as myfile:
    content=myfile.read().replace('\n', '\n')


lst = open('ID.list')
Id = list()
for line in lst:
    stuff=line.rstrip()
    stuff.split()
    Id.append(stuff)
for ele in Id:
    tree = etree.XML(content)
    target_elements = tree.xpath('//Iteration[contains(., ele)]')

for element in target_elements:
    print(etree.tostring(element))
```